# Boto3 ContentDisposition inline not working

Tags: amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, boto3

I am using boto3 in my django-restfrmework project for uploading images to amazon. But i am facing issue. My image starting downloading automatically whenever i place url in browser. I set property **ContentDisposition='inline'**, but still my image download. Any trick with this?

```
session = boto3.Session(
                    aws_access_key_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY,
                    aws_secret_access_key=YOUR_SECRET_KEY,
                    region_name=YOUR_AWS_REGION
                )
                s3 = session.resource('s3')
                bucket = s3.Bucket(AWS_BUCKET_NAME)

bucket.put_object(Key=image_name, Body=file, ACL='public-read', ContentDisposition='inline')
```

Comment: Did you verified that ContentDisposition is getting setted properly ?

Comment: @UmairMohammad thanks for response. Can you please elaborate? Yes im sending as it shown above. even ACL param is working but not ContentDisposition

Comment: Upload file and then go to S3 UI and check the properties of the file and check if the header is set properly.

Answer (score 4):

When you check the Properties of image file uploaded in s3 bucket, and goto MetaData in it, you'll see two keys, one is ContentDisposition:inline and other one is Content-Type: binary/octet-stream. So, your file is being downloaded instead of inline view because whenever there is lack of ContentType, by deault it sets to binary/octet-stream in s3 bucket which is a downloadable file type. So you just have to correct that to image/jpeg.

Replace:

```
bucket.put_object(Key=image_name, Body=file, ACL='public-read', ContentDisposition='inline')
```

To:

```
bucket.put_object(Key=image_name, Body=file, ACL='public-read', ContentDisposition='inline', ContentType='image/jpeg')
```

I hope this works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Vipul for the response. May be possible this work but i use other way to upload the file, thats worked for me. Someone if trying please try this and let me know i will mark solved this answer.